# Maximum call stack size exceeded on the ship battle generator

Tags: javascript

So, I need the random ship generator which placing ships at least at 1 point distance. But stack is overflowing and I can't fix it.

2d massive: 0 - nothing 1 - miss 2 - hidden ship 3 - damaged|destroyed ship

```js
var pole = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];

    var
        count = 4,
        random = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

//Onload

    window.onload = placeOneShip(4);

//Functions

    function placeOneShip(count) {
    if (count > 0) {

        random = Math.round(Math.random(64));
        
        j = Math.floor(random/8); // Start on y
        i = random - (Math.floor(random/8) * 8) - 1; // Start on x

        for (var y = j; y < j + 2; y++) {
            for (var x = i; x < i + 2; x++) {

                if (j >= 0 && i >= 0) { //Check fon undefined
                    if (pole[j, i] == 0) {
                        // All ok
                    } else {
                        placeOneShip(count); // Retry
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        pole[j, i] = 2; // Ship here
    console.log(pole)
        console.log(j + ' ' + i); // Log ship position 4 debug (delite later) 
        placeOneShip(count - 1); // Next ship
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have infinite recursion because every time you retry you start at the same coordinates? `placeOneShip(count); // Retry`

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be doing this with recursion. Just use a loop.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's cracking on randomize

Answer (score 0):

The mistacke was based on random. There was only 2 cells wheree ship should spawn, but there mustn't be any ships around ather in radius of 1 cell. So stack overfloaded.